# Can Cure Light Wounds be used inside an Anti-magic field?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

[Antimagic Field](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm) notes that:

> (The effects of instantaneous conjurations are not affected by an antimagic field because the conjuration itself is no longer in effect, only its result.)

How does a healed wound (or healing a wound) function within a field?

Comment: Worth noting that the *Tome of Battle* Crusader’s various healing maneuvers from Devoted Spirit **are** extraordinary and function inside of an AMF. Be aware that losing HP is not equivalent to being wounded – certainly no could survive the damage that even low-level characters can take if that were the case. HP is a **heavily** abstracted system. Losing HP just means you are that much closer to beaten: it’s losing that “heroic spirit” that allows you to function as a hero to begin with.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't heal a wound with magic in an AMF, because magic does not work there.

However, cure wounds is an instantaneous spell that modifies the recipient creating a new, stable condition, like when you punch some clay: Even if you're no more punching it, the clay retains the new form.
So, if a creature that has been healed by magic enters an AMF, there's no spell in effect and the effects of the healing spells are not reverted.

It would be different if it was some heal-over-time spell, regeneration-like. While the character with such a spell healing him is inside the AMF the healing stops - and resumes once he gets out (while the round count of the spell continues to go).

The text you quoted also means that if somebody uses a conjuration spell like [*acid arrow*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/acidArrow.htm) and shoots it at somebody that's inside an AMF, the acid arrow is not made of magic: it's real acid that continues to exist in the AMF and damages the target as intended.

Answer (score 5):

Antimagic has always prohibited the casting of any magic or magical abilities.

the 3.5 DMG note the following in Chapter 8 (Numbering mine, original is bullets):

> 1. No supernatural ability, spell-like ability, or spell works in an
>      area of antimagic (but extraordinary abilities still work).
> 2. Antimagic does not dispel magic; it suppresses it. Once a magical
>      effect is no longer affected by the antimagic (the antimagic
>      fades, the center of the effect moves away, and so on), the magic
>      returns. Spells that still have part of their duration left begin
>      functioning again, magic items are once again useful, and so
>      forth.
> 3. Spell areas that include both an antimagic area and a normal
>      area, but are not centered in the antimagic area, still function in
>      the normal area. If the spell’s center is in the antimagic area,
>      then the spell is suppressed.
> 4. Golems and other constructs, elementals, outsiders, and corporeal
>      undead, still function in an antimagic area (though the
>      antimagic area suppresses their spellcasting and their supernatural
>      and spell-like abilities normally). If such creatures are
>      summoned or conjured, however, see below.
> 5. Summoned or conjured creatures of any type, as well as incorporeal
>      undead, wink out if they enter the area of an antimagic
>      effect. They reappear in the same spot once the field goes away.
> 6. Magic items with continuous effects, such as a bag of holding, do
>      not function in the area of an antimagic effect, but their effects
>      are not canceled (so the contents of the bag are unavailable, but
>      neither spill out nor disappear forever).
> 7. Two antimagic areas in the same place do not cancel each other
>      out, nor do they stack.
> 8. Wall of force, prismatic wall, and prismatic sphere are not affected by
>      antimagic. Break enchantment, dispel magic, and greater dispel
>      magic spells do not dispel antimagic. Mordenkainen’s disjunction
>      has a 1% chance per caster level of destroying an antimagic field.
>      If the antimagic field survives the disjunction, no items within it
>      are disjoined.

The first point is the most important; it absolutely precludes spells cast from within or upon those within.  The heal spell thus cannot work, nor can the class abilities that heal instantly. That the spell is instant is of no matter.

The confusion seems to be based upon Point 2 and point 6. Since the spell fails, there's no spell to have continuing effect nor an instant effect.

Note that the lack of effect upon instant spells is upon ones already having gone into effect before the Antimagic Zone (AMZ) is encountered; such spells have literally already ended, and thus can't be affected. They still cannot be cast into, from, or through the AMZ.

Point 4, for reference is an explicit exemption for some types; point 5 is a clarification of point 4, noting what isn't exempted but could be confused for those that are.

Point 6 is a specific example of point 2.

Point 7 and 8 are both about ending the AMZ; point 8 also includes additional exempt spells, and does not include heal spells.